# Why is System.Drawing.Color not an enum

Tags: c#, struct, colors, enums

Why is `System.Drawing.Color` a [struct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/ah19swz4.aspx) and `System.ConsoleColor` an [enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the console only supports a small set of colours, whereas `System.Drawing` models all possible 24-bit colours (32-bit with alpha). That's over 4 billion possible colours, which would be a big enum!

Here are the console colours:

[image]

There are 16 foreground, plus 16 background colours.

Note that in `System.Drawing` [some colours are given names](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color(v=vs.110).aspx), but they're not an enum -- they're static fields, such as `Color.Red` and `Color.Aquamarine`.

The same is true of [`System.Windows.Media.Color`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.color(v=vs.110).aspx) (as used in WPF).

Answer (score 1):

Because there are 16 well known colors for console, but 16777216 colors (plus 256 alpha levels for each) that can be used in general. Would you like to name all 4 billion of them and write code that then converts these enums back into actual RGBA values?